# How can I get the parent ASIN of an item?

Tags: amazon-product-api

To get the variations of an item, we need to pass the ASIN of its parent item. But given a child item, is it possible to get the parent ASIN via the Amazon Product Advertising API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, after a long search, I can say that it is not possible to get the parent ASIN via the current version (2011-08-02) of the Amazon Product Advertising API.

I hope in the future Amazon it will provide this functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Include VariationMatrix in your ResponseGroup. This is poorly documented in Amazon but it will give you the ASIN and ParentASIN for each Item. As far as I know it works in both ItemSearch and ItemLookup. Then do an ItemLookup using the ParentASIN and you will get Variations returned with an array of Items, all showing their ASIN, their variation dimensions, offers, etc.

Comment: Interesting, I spent a lot of time trying to get the audio previews, ie a direct link to MP3 tracks not a page where the track can be purchased and previewed. I don't remember reading a thing a bout VariationMatrix, perhaps it will help with my long time Amazon Product API frustration, but I can get audio previews from iTunes for most tracks so my enthusiasm for trying to solve that problem has waned... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't found your answer yet, the following request helped me get the parent ASIN.

```
$baba_item = array(
'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
'ItemId' => 'B003O6CB6S',  
'ResponseGroup' => 'Variations'
);

$baba_result =  $amazon->queryAmazon($baba_item);
$parentASINi= $baba_result->Items->Item->ParentASIN;
```